# How do we use INSERT with WHERE in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, discord.py

`await self.client.db.execute('INSERT INTO config (watcher_channel) VALUES ($1) WHERE guild_id = $2', channel.id, ctx.guild.id)`

Im using `asyncpg`, idk why it gives me syntax error.

Error:
`Command raised an exception: PostgresSyntaxError: syntax error at or near "WHERE"`

Comment: Where does guild_id come from? You try to create a new record, that does not exists and therefor doesn't have any values. A comparison with something that doesn't exists, won't work. That also why WHERE isn't supported by INSERT, there is nothing to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrase your insert as `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
await self.client.db.execute(
    'INSERT INTO config (watcher_channel) SELECT $1 WHERE guild_id = $2',
    channel.id, ctx.guild.id)
```

Comment: Where should guild_id come from? It's not part of any record because you don't select any record from any table.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you really want an `update`:

```
update config
    set watcher_channel = $1
    where guild_id = $2;
```

`INSERT` inserts a complete new row into the table.  I suspect that you simply want to *update* a value in an existing row.